# How Can I Send locale, with ServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, locale, server-side-rendering

I can access context.locale.
How can ı send this information to nextjs backend ?

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log(context.locale);
  // output "en"
  let response;
  try {
    const { data } = await getAllServices();
    response = { data: data };
  } catch (err) {
    response = { err: err.message };
  }
  return {
    props: { response },
  };
}
```

There is nothing about locale in req Why ?

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
console.log(req)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you should pass the **locale** as a query parameter to your backend.

For example let's assume that your backend url for **getAllServices** api is:

`https://my-backend.com/all-services`

You should add a query parameter for your locale like this:

`https://my-backend.com/all-services?locale=en`

And then in your backend, get the locale like this:

`req.query['locale']`

Comment: I know but o don't want to use as a query param. There might be better solution. Thank you for asnwer